# AspNetTempFiles being cleared prematurely

Tags: asp.net, iis-8.5

Thanks for taking a look at this.

We are trying to perform an in place precompile for our .Net webapp running on iis 8.5 using aspnet_compiler.exe.

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_compiler.exe -m /LM/W3SVC/1/ROOT -errorstack
```

It is generating files into our site's temp folder. Unfortunately, we are seeing those files disappear almost as soon as they are created. I was thinking that it might be caused by an app pool recycle but we have that set to happen once a day. Here is the compilation element from our web.config.

```
 <compilation debug="false" defaultLanguage="c#" targetFramework="4.6.1" numRecompilesBeforeAppRestart="5000" batch="true" optimizeCompilations="true" tempDirectory="C:\AspNetTempFiles">
```

If my understanding is correct, when we precompile our app, the temp folder is supposed to fill up with files that then remain there to help with the performance during a first time page load. These files are disappearing so quickly that they even get removed during the precompilation stage and the first page hits always take a long time to load (which is why we started looking into precompilation in the first place!)

We have precompiled a copy of the site on a local box and we see the temp AspNetTempFiles folder fill to the point where there are about 10k files available. However, as soon as we hit a page, a large chunk of those files are removed from the folder.

Any thoughts as to why these files might be getting cleared out before an app pool restart? Or might there be a reason why a recycle is being forced faster than normal?

Thanks again!